# Twitter uid is null when using Omniauth (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I am using Omni auth to authenticate twitter account in my rails application.

I could able to get the **uid** parameter before, but now its returning null like below

```
{"provider":"twitter","uid":null,

"info":

{
"nickname":"boobalanv",
"name":"Boobalan",
"location":"",
"image":"<image url>",
"description":"",
"urls":
{
"Website":null,
"Twitter":"http://twitter.com/boobalanv"}},
"credentials":
```

I am testing this in my local host.

What am i doing wrong or is twitter has stopped providing user id?

**Update :**

Actually i added client options for authorize path in `initializers/omniauth.rb` like below
(By doing so only authorization will include prvilege to access direct message)

`provider :twitter, Rails.application.config.consumer_key , Rails.application.config.consumer_secret , authorize_params: {force_login: 'true'}, client_options: {authorize_path: '/oauth/authorize'}`

only after doing this i am having this issue with uid = null, when i remove this option ' client_options: {authorize_path: '/oauth/authorize'}' its working fine..

any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for this.

The uid field is null when **authorize_path** is set to **"/oauth/authorize"**.
Instead we can get the Twitter user id by using the below

```
auth['extra']['raw_info']['id']
```